# When Open many times, SELECT2 options convert in Searching text

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I don't know if it's normal behavior, but if I open select2 several times, my options become the text "Searching".

What could be causing that?

Update to the latest available version of Select2 and the same thing continues.

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of this? Perhaps a jsfiddle? If not that then maybe your js and html. Offhand Id guess that something is triggering an ajax call to search for autocomplete options or similar but its hard to know for sure without seeing the code or behavior

Comment: Hi @WesleySmith this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2ekvobzu/2/

Comment: Hmm, is it doing it to you in that fiddle now?

Comment: That's right @WesleySmith

Comment: Its not happening for me. Try this, open the fiddle in an incognito window, or a different browser profile. Does the issue stop? If it does, its very likely that you have a browser extension or something similar that is interfering with the otherwise working select2 elements

Comment: @WesleySmith Incognito window - select2 https://imgur.com/a/vlU2gnN - New Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t5gxsu6a/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206632/discussion-between-der-schwarze-konig-and-wesley-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if its a bug or a feature, but this is happening because of the `id` attribute on the options. If you remove the ids from the options tags, it stops.

Comment: I tested wthout the id attribute, work perfectly, thank you Wesley